# PHP PDO bindValue() with Array Data

Tags: php, pdo

Can i use bindValue() like given in the code below, is it valid.

```
foreach ($myArray as $paramName => $Data)
{
  $paramStr = ":".$paramName;
  $preparedQuery->bindValue($paramStr, $Data);
}
```

My concern is about binding with variable $Data, which will have different values through the loop.

Comment: bindValue happens at call time so yes you can do that and you don't have to worry about `$Data` changing values.

Comment: Well, did you try it?